# Pipeline GitHub -> Travis CI -> Docker

Tags: docker, automated-tests, travis-ci

I have a [github-repository](https://github.com/ctlab/phantasus), that is linked to [automated build on Docker](https://hub.docker.com/dzenkova/phantasus). Consequently, on each commit to master-branch, docker triggers building of Docker-image.

Also, each commit is tested by [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/ctlab/phantasus) automatically.

My question is: is there any way to trigger Docker only if travis finishes successfully? Do I need some sort of webhook or something like that for my goal?

Comment: Have you read https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/docker/? I think you can do all of this from the CI side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could trigger the Travis CI test after the repository is pushed. Then, in the [deploy step](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment) you could trigger a build on Docker. Or even do the build inside Travis, and just push the image to the repository you are using.

Travis has a nice overview of how to make this flow happen [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/docker/).

The gist is that you're going to need to have `sudo: required`, so you're going to be running in a VM instead of inside Docker, as is the standard way in Travis. You also need to add `docker` as a service, much like you'd add `redis` or `postgres` for an integration test. The [Pushing Docker Image to a Registry](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/docker/#Pushing-a-Docker-Image-to-a-Registry) section has a lot of info on setting things up for the actual deployment. I'd use an actual `deploy` step with the `script` provider, rather than `after_success`, but that's up to you.